# JSON.parse() returning strings

Tags: javascript, html, json, dom

I am trying to iterate through an array of objects and populate an HTML select element with options whose values are the entire contents of each object.  The population is successful, but the objects are turned into strings in the process and I do not know how to turn them back into objects.

Running them through JSON.parse() gives me "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1 at JSON.parse."  My research suggests that this happens when you use JSON.parse() on something that is already an object, but running typeOf() on the data beforehand reveals that it is a string.

I do not get this error if I instead run the data through JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)), but its output remains a string.

Please help me understand what I am misapprehending about JSON.parse().  Thank you.

```
const selectors = document.getElementsByClassName("ingredientSelector");
const cookButton = document.getElementById("cookButton");

//very large array of ingredient objects

let selectorOptions = "<option value = 'Nothing'>Nothing</option>";
 for (let i = 0; i < ingredients.length; i++){
     selectorOptions += ("<option value = '" + ingredients[i] + "'>" + ingredients[i].name + "</option>");
 }
Array.prototype.forEach.call(selectors,function(selector){
    selector.innerHTML = selectorOptions;
});

function cook(ingredients){
    console.log("Cooking with ingredients: " + ingredients);
}

cookButton.addEventListener("click", function(){
    let ingredients = [];
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(selectors,function(selector){
        if(selector.value !== 'Nothing'){
            console.log(typeof(selector.value))
            JSON.parse(selector.value);
            let JSONString = JSON.stringify(selector.value);
            console.log(typeof(JSONString));
            let JSONObject = (JSON.parse(JSONString));
            console.log(typeof(JSONObject));
            console.log(JSONObject.name);
        }
        console.log(ingredients);
        cook(ingredients);
    });
});
```

Comment: Good question so far, do you think you could share the console output you get from all of these `console.log`s as well as the error itself? It would help people trace through the code and try to statically identify the issue!

Comment: Can you put an example of a value within the option?

Comment: @Klaycon Sure thing.  The error from JSON.parse(selector.value) is...

VM44:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at botw_cooking.js:1204
    at HTMLCollection.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (botw_cooking.js:1201)

Comment: @Klaycon and if I comment that out, all three console.log(typeof)... commands return "string," and console.log(JSONObject.name); returns "undefined."

Comment: @balzacLeGeek the options appear in the console as...

<option value = '[object Object]'>Acorn</option> 

...but if I log the objects themselves before adding them, they would resemble...

effectStrength: null
effectType: null
heartRestoration: 1
name: "Acorn"
timeAdded: 50
type: "food"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is how you're building the `value` properties for the `option`s you're inserting into each selector. On this line:

```
selectorOptions += ("<option value = '" + ingredients[i] + "'>" + ingredients[i].name + "</option>");
```

Your comment says that `ingredients` is an array of objects, so `ingredients[i]` will be an object. *Concatenating* an object to a string will, by default, turn it into `[object Object]` - and this is what's causing your error. You're ending up with an option that looks something like this, perhaps:

```
<option value = '[object Object]'>Raw Prime Meat<object>
```

There's two perfectly valid approaches here. You can either store the *ingredient index* in the option values, which you can then use to lookup the ingredient from your master array later, or you should use `JSON.stringify(ingredients[i])` to turn the object into a `JSON.parse`able string to make your code work as-is.

So this would work fine:

```
selectorOptions += ("<option value = '" + JSON.stringify(ingredients[i]) + "'>" + ingredients[i].name + "</option>");
```

Comment: Ohhh.  I saw [object Object] being logged but thought that was just what it was displaying, and that my values were still there.  Didn't realize it was literally just the string "[object Object]."  Thanks for your help!